# Minimal python docker image with nix

Tags: python, docker, nix

How can I build a python docker image of minimal size with nix?

The smallest I was able to get was 133MB. I think I can do better because official python slim image is ~40MB.

Here is what I tried:

##### `buildImage`: 133MB

```hs
{ pkgs ? import ./pinned.nix { }
, pkgsLinux ? import ./pinned.nix { system = "x86_64-linux"; }
}:

pkgs.dockerTools.buildImage {
  name = "python-docker";
  tag = "latest";
  config = {
    Cmd = [ "${pkgsLinux.python3}/bin/python" "--version" ];
  };
}
```

##### `buildImage` with `copyToRoot`: 219MB

```hs
{ pkgs ? import ./pinned.nix { }
, pkgsLinux ? import ./pinned.nix { system = "x86_64-linux"; }
}:

pkgs.dockerTools.buildImage {
  name = "python-docker";
  tag = "latest";
  copyToRoot = [ pkgsLinux.python3 ];
  config = {
    Cmd = [ "python3" "--version" ];
  };
}
```

##### `buildImage` with `contents`: 219MB

```hs
{ pkgs ? import ./pinned.nix { }
, pkgsLinux ? import ./pinned.nix { system = "x86_64-linux"; }
}:

pkgs.dockerTools.buildImage {
  name = "python-docker";
  tag = "latest";
  contents = [ pkgsLinux.python3 ]; # shows warning because `contents` is deprecated
  config = {
    Cmd = [ "python3" "--version" ];
  };
}
```

##### `buildLayeredImage`: 133MB

```hs
{ pkgs ? import ./pinned.nix { }
, pkgsLinux ? import ./pinned.nix { system = "x86_64-linux"; }
}:

pkgs.dockerTools.buildLayeredImage {
  name = "python-docker";
  tag = "latest";
  config = {
    Cmd = [ "${pkgsLinux.python3}/bin/python" "--version" ];
  };
}
```

##### `buildLayeredImage` with `copyToRoot`: does not work

```hs
{ pkgs ? import ./pinned.nix { }
, pkgsLinux ? import ./pinned.nix { system = "x86_64-linux"; }
}:

pkgs.dockerTools.buildLayeredImage {
  name = "python-docker";
  tag = "latest";
  copyToRoot = [ pkgsLinux.python3 ];
  config = {
    Cmd = [ "python3" "--version" ];
  };
}
```

##### `buildLayeredImage` with `contents`: 134 MB

```hs
{ pkgs ? import ./pinned.nix { }
, pkgsLinux ? import ./pinned.nix { system = "x86_64-linux"; }
}:

pkgs.dockerTools.buildLayeredImage {
  name = "python-docker";
  tag = "latest";
  contents = [ pkgsLinux.python3 ];
  config = {
    Cmd = [ "python3" "--version" ];
  };
}
```

Content of `pinned.nix`:

```hs
import (
  builtins.fetchTarball {
    url = "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/1c6eb4876f71e8903ae9f73e6adf45fdbebc0292.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "15gc5vmpz0wpasra6xmqq2l4cc65g9jm1zfrm16w43hmanrzx3l4";
  }
)
```

Note: I am on a mac M1 laptop

Comment: Did you try (`pkgsLinux.`) `pkgsStatic.python3Minimal`?

Comment: It does not work because it requires to be on a x86_64 linux machine: `error: a 'x86_64-linux' is required to build '/nix/store/dvhsbwpmv5czncysmgc03r62vw9s3758-python3-minimal-static-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl-3.10.7.drv'`

Comment: The other ones are also native linux builds, but those are cached on `cache.nixos.org`, so you don't have to actually build them. If you're going to customize your images, you're probably going to need a linux builder. If you can switch to aarch64-linux, you could run the builder locally. [Here's some help with that](https://github.com/Gabriella439/macos-builder). You won't interact much at all with the VM because these "remote" builds are automatically forwarded there.

Comment: It would be nice if NixOS could provide more static binaries in its cache.

Comment: https://jade.fyi/blog/optimizing-nix-docker/ might give you some pointers